# React Beautiful Dnd : after dropping the item, source and destination indices are undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to `react.js` and trying to create a basic Drag and Drop using 
`react-beautiful-dnd`. I'm unable to find te issue after multiple tries,  below is the code, drag and drop is fine but after dropping `list` is not reordering basically, in `onDragEnd` function `result.source.index` and `result.destination.index` is `undefined`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {
    DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable
} from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

//data
const getItems = (count) => Array.from({length: count}, (v, k) => k).map(k => ({
    id: `item-${k}`,
    content: `item ${k}`
}))

/** Reorder an array, moving the item at $startIndex to $endIndex. */
const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list)
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1)
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed)
    return result
}

// inline style
const grid = 8
const getItemStyle = (dragabbleStyle, isDragging) => ({
    userSelect: 'none',
    padding: grid * 2,
    marginBotom: grid,
    background: isDragging ? 'lightgreen': 'grey',
    ...dragabbleStyle
})
const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver) => ({
    background: isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
    padding: grid,
    width: 250
})

class AppDnD extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: getItems(10)
        }
    }

    onDragEnd = (result) => {
        if(!result.destination) {return}
        console.log(result)
        const items = reorder (
            this.state.items,
            result.source.index,
            result.destination.index,
        )
        this.setState({items})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                        >
                            {this.state.items.map(item => (
                                <Draggable
                                    key={item.id}
                                    draggableId={item.id}
                                >
                                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div
                                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                style={
                                                    getItemStyle(
                                                    provided.draggableProps.style,
                                                    snapshot.isDragging
                                                )}
                                                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                {...provided.draggableProps}
                                            >
                                                {item.content}
                                            </div>
                                            {provided.placeholder}
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </Draggable>
                            ))}
                            </div>
                        )}
                        </Droppable>
                    </DragDropContext>
                )
            }
        }

export default AppDnD;
```

Could someone give me a breakdown how drag and drop works in `react-beautiful-dnd`. My actual target is to do a drag and drop behaviour for a Table, it would be great if someone provide some points for it.

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, in `<Draggable>` component we need to define `id={i}` attribute. The whole statement would look like this `

Comment: I strongly suggest to follow this (https://github.com/jacobwicks/rbdnd-2-list-example) guide to understand `react-beautiful-dnd` (much better than any other source I've seen online)

Answer (score 0):

Droppable id needs an index which is changing

```
array.map((items, index) => (
    <Droppable droppableId={index.toString()}>
        {(provided) => (
            <div className="calendar-col"   {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} key={index}>
                <div className="calendar-date-cell">
                    <div className="date-content">
                        {items[0]?.startDate}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </Droppable>
))
```